# common term for create,update,delete

Tags: sql

What is the common term that we can use for Create/Update/Delete Operations?
Can we use 'transaction'?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All these are called [DML (Data Manipulation Language)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Manipulation_Language) statements.

They may be called transactions in the business world (e.g a transaction is something that modifies my account) but in the database world selects can also be transactional.

Also note that instead of `create` you most probably mean `insert`.

Answer (score 11):

CUD (Create, Update, Delete) operations is used quite often to describe these actions.  CUD is a play on CRUD (create, read, update, delete).  You can see Microsoft even references this in their materials:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546187.aspx

Answer (score 4):

The word 'Process' can be used. Alternatively the words 'Alter' and 'Change' might be useful too. However, they don't sound like they include Create.

Answer (score 1):

It is commonly referred to as [CRUD (Create, Read, Update and Delete)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete).

Comment: ... without the R ... 